# jQuery Selector equivalent for ":not"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to achieve desired output below with pure JavaScript since jQuery isn't available on the page where I am executing code.

HTML:

```
<div id="firstDiv">
    <b>Item 1:</b> tacos
</div>
```

Output:

```
tacos
```

How can I achieve this?

My failed attempt with jQuery:

```
$("#firstDiv:not('b')").text().trim();
```

Comment: your selector doesn't make any sense. `#firstDiv` is not a `<b>` tag and never will be, because it's a `<div>`

Comment: Can you explain the difference between `#firstDiv:not('b')` and `#firstDiv :not('b')` because with the first one I get the desired output, and with the second I get an empty output.

Comment: If you saw that in a stylesheet, would you know what the difference is? `#someid:not('b') { color: black; }` vs `#someid :not('b') { color: black; }` or, even simpler, `a.someclass {color: black;}` vs `a .someclass {color: black;}`

Comment: I agree with you, logically `#firstDiv:not('b')` would mean "find an id='firstDiv' where the tag is not b" and `#firstDiv :not('b')` would mean "find an id='firstDiv' and then look for any children where the tag is not b" but I'm not observing that in the console when I enter these selectors.

Comment: You can't select a text node using element selectors. That's why the answer below wrapped `tacos` in a `<span>`, so that it can be selected.

Comment: css cannot select or apply styles to text, it can only select and apply styles to the element that contains the text. jQuery's selector engine follows this same principle.

Comment: I suggest deleting this question and re-asking it, not mentioning jQuery at all. All you did by mentioning jquery was side-track it by the fact that what you are trying to do can't be done the way you were trying to do it. What you actually need to do is target the text node directly and change it, if you can't modify the html to wrap the text node in it's own element.

Comment: I decided to just edit the question, I think there is a good discussion on this question which would be a shame to delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:not()` is a CSS3 selector, and as such is available via `querySelector[All]` in modern browsers.

```js
alert(document.querySelector("#firstDiv :not(b)").innerText.trim());
```

```html
<div id="firstDiv">
    <b>Item 1:</b> <span>tacos</span>
</div>
```

I've also wrapped the "tacos" in a `<span>` to facilate access, and changed the selector to select descendants that aren't `<b>`s.

Comment: I tried that, I get this: "SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#firstDiv:not('b')' is not a valid selector."

Comment: @hawaiianchimp I just noticed that, i fixed the selector and DOM.

Comment: When I try your selector `#firstDiv :not(b)` I get: "Cannot read property 'innerText' of null" which means the selector isn't returning anything however when I change the selector to `#firstDiv:not(b)` I get the desired result, what's going on here? And btw I can't change the HTML, I'm executing the code on a page that I don't control.

Comment: @hawaiianchimp When i did it without the space, it included the "Item 1" in the alert. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Oh my mistake, I ended up doing .remove() and removing the `<b>Item 1:</b>` part which is why I was getting the desired result for the selector without the space, but I am still getting `Cannot read property 'innerText' of null` when I try to run your selector on the page. I guess my problem isn't with the selector it must be something else. Thanks!

Comment: I understand now why you needed to add the <span> to `tacos` but is there a way to do it without modifying the HTML?

Comment: @hawaiianchimp No, you either have to wrap the text, or strip the `<b>`.